# Why blocking instead of looping?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, busy-loop

What are some reasons why writing the following piece of code is considered bad practice?

```
  while (someList.isEmpty()) {
    try {
      Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
  }
  // Do something to the list as soon as some thread adds an element to it.
```

To me, picking an arbitrary value to sleep is not good practice, and I would use a `BlockingQueue` in this situation, but I'd like to know if there is more than one reason why one shouldn't write such code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It imposes an average delay of 50 milliseconds before the event is acted on, and it wakes up 10 times a second when there's no event to handle. If neither of those things particularly matter, then it's just inelegant.

Comment: Just wondering, isn't this how wait functions work internally anyway? (Excluding the exception obviously.)

Comment: @Mehrdad- Typically no.  Usually the threads are placed in a "wait queue" and not given any processor time.  When some event occurs that would wake them, they are placed back into the run queue so that they will be scheduled.  This means that you could have a million sleeping threads without any loss in performance if only two or three threads are active at any one time.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Then how exactly does the OS figure out whether the threads should be awoken at a particular time slice? Shouldn't it check the state of the thread in a loop at every time slice?

Comment: @Mehrdad The OS doesn't find whether they should be awoken, the event occurring itself wakes them. It's the difference between getting up every five minutes to see if the mail has arrived and having the mailman ring your door bell. The code above wakes up ten times a second to see if the event has occurred. The proper way to do is to have the event *itself* wake the thread when it occurs.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Events aren't magical. It's the OS itself that manages the event, so it's the OS that wakes up the thread. So how does it work internally, if not by polling? Is it through an interrupt? (Which interrupt?)

Comment: The event itself wakes the thread. It's not by polling or by an interrupt. The code that handles the event itself (the same code that sets whatever it is the thread that polls would be testing) makes all the threads on the wait queue ready to run. Somewhere there has to be some other code that changes the result of `someList.isEmpty`. With a proper event, that code also wakes any threads that are blocked waiting for that change.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You seem to say "the event" as though it's something outside the OS, which it obviously isn't. *Something* has to trigger the event, and more importantly, *something* has to check whether it has been fired or not, so my question is, what is it?

Comment: It's whatever code changes the result of `someList.isEmpty`. Presumably, it's the code that puts something on that list. In this case, the event is "something is put on someList, such that it is no longer empty". The code that does that can also, trivially, wake any thread that is waiting for the list to be non-empty. That way, no polling is needed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Er, what? What if the code is simply a separate thread saying `_isEmpty = true;`, and the implementation `isEmpty()` simply returns `_isEmpty`? Who is awakening what here?

Comment: @Mehrdad- Typically just setting `_isEmpty` would not wake up any threads.  Most of the time that a thread is waiting on some variable, there is some sort of condition variable or monitor that is notified that a change has been made precisely so the OS can wake up any waiting threads.

Comment: It can't be `_isEmpty = true;` because that contains no synchronization that guarantees another thread ever sees that change in value. It has to contain appropriate synchronization code (such as `volatile`, `synchronized`, or whatever). The definition of "appropriate" is up to the coder, and it can include or not include waking any threads blocked waiting for that change at the coder's option. I'm saying it *should* include waking any such threads so that they don't have to poll.

Comment: @templatetypedef, David: Ooh hmm yeah I think I see what you mean now, though I'm still wondering about the precise details at the CPU level (going through [ReactOS](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d0/df5/xdk_2kefuncs_8h_aef0617cb2d915adfe4495d3d7c1dd5a1.html#aef0617cb2d915adfe4495d3d7c1dd5a1) at the moment to try and figure out what they do exactly). Thanks for the replies!

Comment: The blocking thread sets itself to "not ready to run", adds itself to the wake queue, checks to make sure the event hasn't already occurred (in which case, it sets itself back to ready to run and returns) and then calls the scheduler. When it wakes up, it checks to make sure it can make forward progress and if not, goes back on the wake queue. When the event occurs, the waking thread marks that the event has taken place and then goes through every thread on the wake queue and sets it ready to run and calls the scheduler to possibly pre-empt. (That's a simplification, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons not to do this.  First, as you've noted, this means that there may be a large delay between the time that an event occurs that the thread should respond to and the actual response time, since the thread may be sleeping.  Second, since any system has only so many different processors, if you have to keep kicking important threads off of a processor so that they can tell the thread to go to sleep another time, you decrease the total amount of useful work done by the system and increase the power usage of the system (which matters in systems like phones or embedded devices).

Answer (score 1):

The loop is an excellent example of what not to do. ;)

---

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
```

There is no need to get the currentThread() as this is a static method.  It is the same as

```
Thread.sleep(100);
```

---

```
catch (Exception e) {}
```

This is very bad practice.  So bad I wouldn't suggest you put this even in examples, as someone might copy the code.  A good portion of questions on this forum would be solved by printing out and reading the exception given.

---

```
You don't need to busy wait here. esp. when you expect to be waiting for such a long time.  Busy waiting can make sense if you expect to be waiting a very very short amount of time. e.g.

// From AtomicInteger
public final int getAndSet(int newValue) {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        if (compareAndSet(current, newValue))
            return current;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it should be quite rare that this loop needs to go around more than once, and exponentially less likely to go around many times. (In a real application, rather than a micro-benchmark) This loop might be as short as 10 ns, which is not a long delay.

---

It could wait 99 ms needlessly.  Say the producer is adding an entry 1 ms later, it has waited a long time for nothing.

The solution is simpler and clearer.

```
BlockingQueue<E> queue = 

E e = queue.take(); // blocks until an element is ready.
```

---

The list/queue is only going to change in another thread and a much simpler model for managing threads and queues is to use an ExecutorService

```
ExecutorService es =

final E e = 
es.submit(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       doSomethingWith(e);
   }
});
```

As you can see, you don't need to work with queues or threads directly.  You just need to say what you want the thread pool to do.

Answer (score 0):

you also introduce race conditions to your class. if you were using a blocking queue instead of a normal list - the thread would block until there is a new entry in the list. In your case a second thread could put and get an element from the list while your worker thread is sleeping and you would not even notice.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, you also have a race condition if you have more than one thread removing items from the queue:

1. queue is empty
2. thread A puts an element into the queue
3. thread B checks whether the queue is empty; it isn't
4. thread C checks whether the queue is empty; it isn't
5. thread B takes from the queue; success
6. thread C takes from the queue; failure

You could handle this by atomically (within a `synchronized` block) checking if the queue is empty and, iff not, taking an element from it; now your loop looks just a hair uglier:

```
T item;
while ( (item = tryTake(someList)) == null) {
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // it's almost never a good idea to ignore these; need to handle somehow
    }
}
// Do something with the item

synchronized private T tryTake(List<? extends T> from) {
    if (from.isEmpty()) return null;
    T result = from.remove(0);
    assert result != null : "list may not contain nulls, which is unfortunate"
    return result;
}
```

*or* you could have just used a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: Don't you mean `remove(0)`?  I assume you don't want to ignore the first element.

Comment: In your description you refer to a `queue` but in your code you use a `List`.  This could be confusing.  You could use `Queue.remove()`;  BTW a LinkedList is also a Queue.

Comment: The OP referred to `someList` (not `someQueue` or `someLinkedList`) but `BlockingQueue`, so I've kept that dichotomy in my answer.

Comment: In that case, I would have tried to refer the a `list` consistently in the code and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add directly to the exellent answers given by David, templatetypedef etc. - if you want to avoid inter-thread comms latency and resource-waste, don't do inter-thread comms with sleep() loops.

Preemptive scheduling/dispatching:

At CPU level, interrupts are the key.  The OS does nothing until an interrupt occurs that causes its code to be entered.  Note that, in OS-terms, interrupts come in two flavours - 'real' hardware interrupts that cause drivers to be run and 'software interrupts' - these are OS system calls from already-running threads that can potentially cause the set of running threads to change.  Keypresses, mouse-movements, network cards, disks, page-faults all generate hardware interrupts. The wait and signal functions, and sleep(), belong to that second category.  When a hardware interrupt causes a driver to be run, the driver performs whatever hardware-management it was designed to do.  If the driver needs to signal the OS that some thread needs to be made running, (perhaps a disk buffer is now full and needs to be processed), the OS provides an entry mechanism that the driver can call instead of directly performing an interrupt-return itself, (important!).

Interrupts like the above examples can make threads that were waiting ready to run and/or can make a thread that is running enter a waiting state.  After processing the code of the interrupt, the OS applies its scheduling algorithm/s to decide if the set of threads that were running before the interrupt is the same as the set that should now be run.  If they are, the OS just interrupt-returns, if not, the OS must preempt one or more of the running threads.  If the OS needs to preempt a thread that is running on a CPU core that is not the one that handled the interrupt, it has to gain control of that CPU core.  It does this by means of a 'real' hardware interrupt - the OS inter-processor driver sets a hardware signal that hard-interrupts the core running the thread that is to be preempted.

When a thread that is to be preempted enters the OS code, the OS can save a complete context for the thread.  Some of the registers will have already been saved onto the stack of the thread by means of the interrupt entry and so saving the stack-pointer of the thread will effectively 'save' all those registers, but the OS will normally need to do more, eg. caches may need to be flushed, the FPU state may need to be saved and, in the case where the new thread to be run belongs to a different process than the one to be preempted, memory-management protection registers will need to be swapped out.  Usually, the OS switches from the interrupted-thread stack to a private OS stack as soon as possible to avoid inflicting OS stack requirements onto every thread stack.

Once the context/s is/are saved, the OS can 'swap in' the extended context/s for the new thread/s that are to be made running.  Now, the OS can finally load the stack-pointer for the new thread/s and perform interrupt-returns to make its new ready threads running.

The OS then does nothing at all.  The running threads run until another interrupt, (hard or soft), occurs.

Important points:

1) The OS kernel should be looked at as a big interrupt-handler that can decide to interrupt-return to a different set of threads than the ones interrupted.

2) The OS can get control of, and stop if necessary, any thread in any process, no matter what state it is in or what core it may be running on.

3) Preemptive scheduling and dispatching does generate all the synchronization etc. problems that are posted about on these forums. The big upside is fast response at thread-level to hard interrupts.  Without this, all those high-performance apps you run on your PC - video streaming, fast networks etc, would be virtually impossible.

4) The OS timer is just one of a large set of interrupts that can change the set of running threads.  'Time-slicing', (ugh - I hate that term), between ready threads only occurs when the computer is overloaded, ie. the set of ready threads is larger than the number of CPU cores available to run them. If any text purporting to explain OS scheduling mentions 'time-slicing' before 'interrupts', it is likely to cause more confusion than explanation.  The timer interrupt is only 'special' in that many system calls have timeouts to back up their primary function, (OK, for sleep(), the timeout IS the primary function:).